# I don't understand why my line is going at an angle

Tags: java, oop

I am in this AP class in highschool and we are using the program JAVA or OOP, I don't even know what it is. In the class we don't have a teacher so we basically have to self teach our self from a packet. I am learning how to draw a face and i am kind off struggling.

Well first off, the prompt here- http://mrlanda.com/ecs/unit%205/Happy%20Face.htm

Look at the picture below to see how it looks like.

MY QUESTION-- Well here is what i got so far and it is stressing me out so much, I DON'T KNOW WHY BUT MY LINE KEEPS GOING IN AN ANGLE. Why does it go in an angle when I am not telling it too.. I am also having a problem with the nose i can't seem to find the spot i want to put it at it keeps going into an angle for some reason.

My code so far

```
import apcslib.*; 
public class DrawSquare 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        DrawingTool marker; 
        SketchPad poster; 

        poster= new SketchPad(600,600); 
        marker= new DrawingTool(poster); 

        //left side of box
        marker.up(); 
        marker.move(0,0); 
        marker.down(); 
        marker.turnRight(180); 
        marker.forward(200); 

        //mouth
        marker.up(); 
        marker.move(40,60); 
        marker.down(); 
        marker.turnRight(90); 
        marker.forward(100); 

        //nose
        marker.up(); 
        marker.move(100,100); 
        marker.down(); 
        marker.turnRight(90); 
        marker.forward(100); 

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the DrawingTool ??what is the library do you use for that

Comment: could you please let me know what is the library did you use for this application? I can see you import code: import apcslib.*; but it's not clear and enough for us to help you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the API docs for DrawingTool](http://www.mrnateghiaslitechnology.com/web_lessons/apcslibdocs/apcslib/DrawingTool.html#move(double,%20double)) the method `move(double, double)` changes the direction of your drawing tool.

Hence if you perform the move to `(40,60)` from the endpoint `(-200,0)` of your previous `forward` move your new direction vector will be `(240,60)`. When rotating this by 90 degrees you will head in direction of `(60,-240)`.

I've made a sketch showing the behaviour (not exactly to scale - I hope I haven't mixed coordinates)...

[image: this is what you are trying]

So you have the following options to fix this:

1. instead moving to `(40,60)` directly you could move to a temporary point before forcing the move to have your desired direction:

   ```
   // mouth
   marker.up(); 
   marker.move(40,50);
   marker.move(40,60); // now you have direction "up"
   marker.down(); 
   marker.forward(100);
   ```
2. or you could just use `move` instead of `forward

   ```
   // mouth
   marker.up(); 
   marker.move(40,60);
   marker.down(); 
   marker.move(40,160); // or whatever your expected target is...
   ```